# Apps script custom formula says "Formula parse error" in the sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[screen shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsimX.png)
[screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5umBK.png)

I've commented the entire body and just returned 0, still it's not working. tried reloading the sheet and stuff. The script is saved too.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to use `;` instead of `,` in the spreadsheet?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @MuhammetYunus the semicolon worked. do you know why we needed a semicolon there? some functions just run with a comma.

Comment: I think this is relating to location of your spreadsheet. See [this](https://youtu.be/ljvB2arCsNQ) video please.

Comment: @MuhammetYunus the video helped, I really appreciate it. so that is something to do with the location hah, but still I'm so confused, why a syntax should be changed over locations, why google did that... 